# Is it possible to change the color of the notification bar?

Tags: android, colors, notification-bar

The iPhone gives the app the ability to change the notification bar's color so you can have it match your app's design without having to hide it completely.

Is there a way to change the notification bar color in Android?

I'm looking to have it force black with white text to be less visually present while using the app, but still there.

I don't want to hide it.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can hide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to change the look of the notification bar from your app.  Your only option would be to make your app full screen, but there are several reasons not to do this.